# How to create a compound (primary) key when using classes as relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

If I have:

```
class Checklist {
   [Key]
   public int ChecklistID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

class ChecklistItem {
   [Key]
   public int ChecklistItemID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

class ChecklistAndItem {
   public ChecklistItem ChecklistItem {get;set;}
   public Checklist Checklist {get;set;}
   String description {get;set;}
}
```

And I want to make a table that has mappings from the ChecklistItemID and ChecklistID used as a composite primary key. This will help me prevent duplicats.

What would the correct mapping be in OnModelCreating() ?

I've tried :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ChecklistAndItem>()
        .HasKey(table => new {table.Checklist.ChecklistID,table.ChecklistItem.ChecklistItemID}
    );
}
```

but that gives me this error:

> The properties expression
>   `'table => new <>f__AnonymousType0'2(
>        ChecklistID = table.Checklist.ChecklistID,
>        ChecklistItemID = table.ChecklistItem.ChecklistItemID
>   )'` is not valid.
>   The expression should represent a property access: `'t => t.MyProperty'`.
>   When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type:
>      `'t => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'`.
>   Parameter name: `propertyAccessExpression`

Comment: I think you would need the Id's as properties as well - I dont believe it can create the compound key using navigational properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wasn't possible in EF6. Fortunately EF Core allows you to use [shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) in PK (in addition to FK).

All you need is to make sure the shadow properties are explicitly defined and then use `HasKey` overload with `params string[] propertyNames`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ChecklistAndItem>()
    .Property<int>("ChecklistID");

modelBuilder.Entity<ChecklistAndItem>()
    .Property<int>("ChecklistItemID");

modelBuilder.Entity<ChecklistAndItem>()
    .HasKey("ChecklistID", "ChecklistItemID");
```